# HTML/CSS - Text-align invalid in media queries

Tags: html, css

I am editing the CSS of a DataTable plugin, When my window is at 839px or less I want my search filter to be on the left and when it's 840px or bigger I want it on the far right.

If I use only the text-align rule I will get an invalid value when the media query kicks in.

I managed to pull it off using, text-align to pull it on way when it's 839px or less and Flex when it's 840px or more, just wandering if I can do it cleaner.

Code I used.

```
.dataTables_filter {
    text-align: right !important;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 839px) {
    .dataTables_filter{
        display: flex;
        justify-content: flex-start;
    }
```

Fixed - Thanks DreamTek

Used the following code to make it more uniform and clean.

```
.dataTables_filter {
    float: right;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 839px) {
    .dataTables_filter {
        float: left !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: because in your media queries you have also text-align:right, you only add the others propetries with media-queries but you can overwrite text-align property

Comment: if that is your code, you're also missing a closing bracket on the media query itself.

Comment: Just to clarify. You want to align the `dataTables_filter` div to the left or right side of the table and not to align the text of the filter input?

Comment: @JoshMoto - Sorry, in my code it has a closing bracket, didn't copy properly.

Comment: @Sfili_81, Before I tried with Flex, I tried with // text-align: left !important // But was receiving invalid property, I taught it would over ride it.

Comment: @DreamTek I want to align the filter which in my case is just an input box with placeholder text in it. Text-align allowed me to move the input box which was strange but I didn't complain.

I want the input box to be on the left at 839px or less and on the right when it's 840px or more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is the position of `.dataTables_filter` that you want to edit then you need to adjust the float property used in datatables.

```
.dataTables_filter {
  float:right;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 839px) {
  .dataTables_filter{
    float:left;
  }
}
```

From https://www.datatables.net/

[image]

[image]

Comment: I did as you did but when it's time for the media query to take over it doesn't over write the code.

Comment: I fixed it. I just had to add !important to the float left css rule.